# Load a ML model to predict another dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I trained the RandomForest model and save it, now I want to load the model and assign to it new data to predict value, but I get this error

```
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 110)) while a minimum of 1 is required 
by RandomForestRegressor.
```

How can I fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle

Filename='features_1.csv'
Modelname = 'RandomForest_model_1.sav'
  

# Reading extracted features file    
df = pd.read_csv(Filename,error_bad_lines=False,header=None)

# Fill NANs with Means of columns
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf],np.nan, inplace=True)
df.fillna(df.mean(),inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df =np.isnan(df) 

df.drop(df[df[4] < 90].index, inplace=True)
df.drop(df[df[5] < 40].index, inplace=True)
df.drop(df[df[10] < 50].index, inplace=True)   

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = np.array(df).astype("float32")
print(df.shape)


model = pickle.load(open(Modelname, 'rb'))
predictions=model.predict(df)
print(predictions)
```

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem and googling quite a bit I found a post-https://github.com/llSourcell/Make_Money_with_Tensorflow_2.0/issues/7

so it seems that if you download a too small dataset it will throw that error. Download a .csv from 1962 and it'll be big enough ;).

Now, I just have to find the right parameters for my dataset...as I'm adapting this to another type o prediction... Hope it helps